# How to section a list view in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-foreach

I am working through "100 Days of SwiftUI in Hacking with Swift. I have a list of expense items that I want to section out, so Personal is one set of items and Business is another for example.

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        List {
            ForEach(expenses.items) { item in
                Section(header: Text(item.type)) {
                    HStack {
                        Text(item.name)
                        Text(String(item.amount))
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .trailing)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With this current code each item becomes its own segment; which makes sense my logic is not great since the for each apply the section to the item at the current iteration of the loop.

I was looking at adding another for each to go through my array and get the expense types but it does not seem to be a valid way to do it; I get some errors that it is a string and not something to iterate over, it seems logically wrong too. My thought was to do a new view for the expense items and then maybe a conditional to decide what section it should go in but not sure. Working on implementing that but figure to ask while I work on trying it out.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? which data should be displayed by sections? how do you define which items go into each section?

Comment: Dictionary grouping, Sectioned fetch request, sectioned query, it just depends on where your data comes from

Comment: You should certainly move the ```Section``` outside the ```ForEach``` and then probably have a second ```Section``` with a second ```ForEach``` for the second set of expenses. If all the expenses are in the same collection then the filtering could be done inside each ```ForEach```, or you could call a function to deliver the filtered expenses to iterate over.

Comment: I want my item.type as the section headers in this case. The data is coming from user defaults.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your last comment:

> I want my item.type as the section headers in this case

I would suggest you have an outer `ForEach` that iterates over the types and an inner `ForEach` that iterates over the items. The `Section` are created at the outer level, the rows of the `List` are created inside the inner `ForEach`.

- For the types, it is probably cleaner to build the set in a separate function or computed property. You might also want to sort the types:

```swift
private var expenseTypes: [String] {
    Array(Set(expenses.items.map { $0.type } )).sorted()
}
```

- For the items, filtering can be done inside the `ForEach`. Perhaps like this:

```swift
List {
    ForEach(expenseTypes, id: \.self) { type in
        Section(header: Text(type)) {
            ForEach(expenses.items) { item in
                if item.type == type {
                    HStack {
                        Text(item.name)
                        Text(String(item.amount))
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .trailing)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

BTW, you mentioned in your original question:

> I get some errors that it is a string and not something to iterate over

This is because `String` does not implement `Identifiable`.  What you need to do is instruct the `ForEach` how to form an id for each `String` item. The code above does exactly this for the array of types. It uses `id: \.self`, which means, use the string itself as the id. It is worth noting that this technique can often be a cause of error, because if you have duplicate strings in the array then they will have the same id. But in this case, the array is the set of unique types, so it is safe.